# How To Pass ManagedObjectContext To Other View Controllers in Special Case

Tags: core-data, ios4, nsmanagedobjectcontext, viewcontroller

I have a rootViewController like so:

Header:

```
@interface ParkingRootViewController : UIViewController {
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
    UIToolbar *toolbar;
    UIBarButtonItem *lastUpdateLabel;

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *lastUpdateLabel;

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *applicationDocumentsDirectory;

-(IBAction)selectHome:(id)sender;
//-(void)loadOverlays;
-(void)testCoreData;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //...

    [self testCoreData];

    //creating label in tool bar 
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 150.0f, 20.0f)];
    label.text = @"last updated...";
    label.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:1.0];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    //label.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:1.0];
    //label.highlighted = YES;
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0];
    label.userInteractionEnabled = NO;

    [lastUpdateLabel initWithCustomView:label];
    [label release];

    [self.view addSubview:self.navigationController.view];

    [self.navigationController.view setFrame:self.view.frame];

}
```

But I need to transfer my managedObjectModel to my table view and then to a map view so that the map view can make queries depending on what the user wants to see. I was consulting some apple sample code which looks like(from Recipes):

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {
    recipeListController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

I know that is in the appDelegate, but I figure that I can do the same when a row is selected or another view is pushed onto the stack, right? The problem is that I have configured most of my view with a nib which looks like so:

[image]

Due to this, I am unable to use a similar strategy that Apple employs to transfer a managedObjectModel to an alternate viewController(in this case PermitListViewController) because I don't access PermitListViewController directly when adding a subview. If anyone has any idea of how I would go about getting my managedObjectModel to my PermitListViewController. Please share! Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I am thinking of placing the managedObjectModel in a singleton class. What are your guys' thoughts on that? Good programming practice? Anything I should be aware of? Thanks.

Comment: I successfully created a singleton class for managedObjectModel. The only real question I have is if this is considered good programming style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a singleton class for the managedObjectModel using [this as a reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CocoaObjects/CocoaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH4-SW32) (scroll down to "Creating a Singleton Instance").

Answer (score 1):

Why not have the `NSManagedObjectContext` on the app delegate? Then it would be easily accessible from all your view controllers, and as they are UI they execute on the main thread, and can therefore share the same MOC.

Comment: Well, it is a little complicated. As I am working on a project that contains many "sub apps" that are opened via modal view, and currently I want each sub app to have its own managedObjectModel, at least initially, so that each app portion will have its own Core Data instance and schema. From there I have no problem moving the managedObjectModel to the appDelegate. But for the time being, I don't want to as I want to keep Core Data instances isolated while my team learns the framework.